# Generate bigrams and replace words in sentence using python

Tags: python-2.7

I have generated a list of bigrams from the sentence using nltk. How can i replace the words in sentences using the bigrams frequency.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you provide  an example of the desired input and output?

Comment: from nltk import ngrams
texting= trans2['New1']
bigram_list=[]
for textnew in texting:
    wordsnew = textnew.split()
    for i in range(len(wordsnew)-1):
        bigram_list.append((wordsnew[i], wordsnew[i+1]))